'LlamaForCausalLM' object has no attribute 'max_seq_length'
I'm fine-tuning llama3 using unsloth , I trained my model and saved it successfully but when I tried loading using  AutoPeftModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained ,then I used TextStreamer from transformer library for streaming the generated text , I got this error:
      8 text_streamer = TextStreamer(tokenizer, skip_prompt = True)
----> 9 _ = model.generate(input_ids, streamer = text_streamer, max_new_tokens = 128, 
     10                    pad_token_id = tokenizer.eos_token_id)
-> 1709         raise AttributeError(f"'{type(self).__name__}' object has no attribute '{name}'")
   1710 
   1711     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value: Union[Tensor, 'Module']) -> None:

AttributeError: 'LlamaForCausalLM' object has no attribute 'max_seq_length'

this is the loading code:
   from peft import AutoPeftModelForCausalLM
    from transformers import AutoTokenizer
    model = AutoPeftModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        "text_To_NoSql", # YOUR MODEL YOU USED FOR TRAINING
        load_in_4bit = True,
    )
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("text_To_NoSql")

this is my text generation code:
input_ids = tokenizer.apply_chat_template(
    messages,
    add_generation_prompt = True,
    return_tensors = "pt",
).to("cuda")

from transformers import TextStreamer
text_streamer = TextStreamer(tokenizer, skip_prompt = True)
_ = model.generate(input_ids, streamer = text_streamer, max_new_tokens = 128, 
                   pad_token_id = tokenizer.eos_token_id)

but when I used Unsloth FastLanguageModel, it worked fine , but I want to use AutoPeftModelForCausalLM because i have issue installing Unsloth locally

Hi! Welcome to SO, Is this the full error message? it looks like some frames are missing…
Also could you try running this in the debugger and look for the line where the attribute max_seq_length is accessed?

yes that't the full error message , it says max_seq_length is not propriety of CausalLM , I searched about it and found that I should use max_length, but the problem is that I'm not passing max_seq_length in the class Name in the first place

can you run the program in the debugger?

Just reinstall the transformer library, and it will work.
!pip install git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers.git
!pip install accelerate

